# Rendering detail on close-up views with lower resolution models?

Tags: rendering

How can close-up views of a model have enough detail, be smooth, and not pixelated when rendered without adding a lot of subdivisions?

Increasing the subdivisions of the model works for improving close-up render quality but render time jumps really high with this option. Is there any better way?

(In the example below, both models are smooth and have displacement and bump maps applied, the only difference is the number of subdivisions.)

For example:

[image: Low resolution model close-up]
Low resolution model close-up

[image: Medium resolution model close-up]
Medium resolution model close-up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Edit mode, select all faces with <kbd>A</kbd>, then press <kbd>T</kbd> to open the toolbar, then select **Shading/UV**, then **Faces**, then **Smooth**.

Is that what you were looking for?